# Segmentation (core dumped)

Tags: c

I have been working on a post fix calculator for standard input and after working on it I ended up getting a saying segmentation fault (core dumped) it doesn't say where it occurs or what caused it and after looking for an explanation of what it means I couldn't really find anything that would help me fix it. So I decided I might as well ask here this is all of the stuff I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stack
{
  int data;
  struct stack *up;
};

void push( struct stack * ptr, int value)
{
  struct stack * tmp;
  tmp = malloc(sizeof(value));
  tmp -> data = value;
  tmp -> up = NULL;
}

int pop(struct stack * ptr)
{
  int value;
  struct stack * tmp;

  tmp = ptr;
  value = tmp-> data;
  ptr = tmp -> up;

  free(tmp);
  return value;
}

int evaluate(int argc,const char * argv[],struct stack * ptr)
{
      int h;
      int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= argc - 1; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "M") == 0)
        {

            int a = pop(ptr);
            int b = pop(ptr);
            h = b*a;
            push(ptr,h);

        }
         else if (strcmp(argv[i], "A") == 0)
          {
            printf("%s\n", "error \0");
            int a = pop(ptr);
            int b = pop(ptr);
            h = b+a;
            push(ptr,h);

        }
        else if (strcmp(argv[i], "D") == 0)
        {

            int a = pop(ptr);
            int b = pop(ptr);
            h = b/a;
            push(ptr,h);


        }
         else if (strcmp(argv[i], "S") == 0)
         {

            int a = pop(ptr);
            int b = pop(ptr);
            h = b-a;
            push(ptr,h);

        }
         else
         {
            printf("%s", "Not an operator");

         }

    }
    return pop(ptr);
}

 int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    struct stack s;
    struct stack *ptr = s.up;
    evaluate(argc,argv,ptr);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Do you know that `argv[0]` is the program name? and `i <= argc - 1` -> `i < argc` is a more **c**-ish way of writing a for loop.

Comment: yeah I just don't understand why the core is dumped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In main you create `struct stack s;` and don't initialize it.

Then you pass `s.up` as the third argument of `evaluate`.

And `evaluate` eventually calls pop on `s.up`, which calls free on `s.up`. But `s.up` is still uninitialized, so it crashes.

Comment: I feel really dumb asking but with the way it is set up how would I do that or do I have to change things so I am able to initialize it in main?

Comment: @user2730962 There are quite a lot of things to fix. You shouldn't try to pop past the top of the stack, that won't work. Your push is wrong, it leaks memory by doesn't push anything. And in your evaluate you pop twice before doing any push, so you never fill the stack but you're always trying to pop things out of it. I'm sure I overlooked some things, but fixing this would be a good start!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are allocating the structs wrong, here

```
tmp = malloc(sizeof(value));
```

you are allocating enough space for a `int` value, so the code that follows invokes undefined behavior leading in your case to a segmentation fault, try it this way

```
tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
```

or

```
tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp));
```

also, always check the success of `malloc()` before dereferencing the pointer, like this

```
void push(struct stack *ptr, int value)
{
  struct stack *tmp;

  tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp));
  if (tmp == NULL)
      return;
  tmp->data = value;
  tmp->up   = NULL;
}
```